# Testing for a missing tag with XQuery/XSD in a xml file at a certain condition

Tags: xml, xsd, xquery

I use XQuery for post XSD validation of an XML file. I have an hierarchy in the file so that the "ab" tag can have a child element "bc" but only for certain attribute value in the "ab" tag. If the country attribute in "ab" is USA then we need to have the child "bc", but when country is DE then the "bc" child element can be omitted. How can this be done in either XSD and XQuery or in a combination?

Below is the code I tried:

I use xpath:

```
<Check id="1" type="XQuery" title="bc 0) 'bc must be provided for country USA and BE but not for for DE'"> <XQuery> &lt;Errors&gt; { for $ab in //XDATA/ab, $bc in $ab/bc   where ($ab/@country = "USA" or $ab/@country = "BE") and (empty($bc))  return (: Query output :) &lt;Error ln="{$ab/@ln}"&gt; &lt;Case&gt; { data($ab/@countryid) } &lt; &lt;/Error&gt; } &lt;/Errors&gt; </XQuery> </Check>
```

Many thanks in advance
BM

Comment: What did you try? Please post example data and do not describe it. Also add expected output.

Comment: well i use both xsd and xquerry. But this is a very special case. I use the built functionalty of xsd, defined my xsd file and all work as expected. Also added an xquerry validator that also work fine

Answer (score 0):

Please find out XQUERY example how to check your expected scenarios:

```
let $x := <ab country="USA"><bc>dsfdsfsd</bc></ab>
let $USA := if($x[@country="USA"][bc]) then "Yes" else "No"
let $DE := if($x[@country="DE"][bc or not(bc)]) then "Yes" else "No"
return
  if($USA="Yes" or $DE="Yes")
  then "Yes"
  else
  if($USA="No" or $DE="No")
  then "No"
  else ()
```

Comment: Hello, and thank you for the code. I use xpath:
    <Check id="1" type="XQuery" title="bc 0) 'bc must be provided for country USA and BE but not for for DE'">
      <XQuery>
     
        &lt;Errors&gt;
        {
        for $ab in //XDATA/ab,
        $bc in $ab/bc


        where

        ($ab/@country = "USA" or $ab/@country = "BE")
        and (empty($bc))


        return

        (: Query output :)

        &lt;Error ln="{$ab/@ln}"&gt;
     
        &lt;Case&gt; { data($ab/@countryid) } &lt;
        &lt;/Error&gt;

        }
        &lt;/Errors&gt;
      </XQuery>
    </Check>

Comment: The problem with this approach is that each "ab" tag may have one or more "bc" tags. so the code above may not be exactly what could work and also most of my code is already using xpath. So i would prefer an xpath aproach.